# Android: How to read the entire stacktrace from LogCat (including the ..X more errors)?

Tags: android, stack-trace, android-logcat

I have an error on my Android Application and one of the really annoying things that LogCat does is write

> exception Caused at android.
>
> at android...
>
> at android...
>
> at android...
>
> and 21 more

I need to read the error inside that 21 more. Is there a way to do it? I've tried filtering the results but no luck.

Comment: have you tried try and catch statements.If not try it

Comment: Ok, so in my application - I get a force close error when my addPreferencesFromResource() method gets called from my PreferenceActivity so I added try-catch statements around this bit. The preference activity started, but there were no widgets there and I got no error outputs of any kind :(

Comment: have you print the  error  with Log.e("",""+e) in catch block

Comment: Yeah, I did. I got no output.

Comment: Have you selected the device from tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [debug the app](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html) and add a conditional breakpoint for your exception, or just a normal breakpoint if you know where it's thrown exactly. Then when you're there, you have full access to the stack trace and, even better, to the context variables when the exception occured.

Comment: Trouble is i'm not sure where to put the breakpoint. I am following an example and I've checked to make sure nothing is different and it fails. I have no idea what part is causing the error.

Comment: That's why I suggested using a conditional breakpoint: you don't have to set a breakpoint at a specific place, you can specify "breakpoint happens whenever XXX exception is thrown"

Comment: Ah! That's new to me (still a beginner), i'll give that a go.